# How can I extract/Match Multiple Words at once from a Excel File with Sublime Text

Tags: csv, match, sublimetext, words

I'm looking for a way to find multiple matches from multiple words at once.
Basically match the selection like in the example, but with many words at once, so Data can be extracted from a bigger list.

Here is an Example:

1 List smaller list with around 200 Lines contains this:

- xWDL15-B01
- xWDL15-CD01
- xWDL15BM-V02
- xWDL15-V01
- xROHVS10-V09
- xDAEMBEK13-V09
- xFEBG16_V10
- ...

But I have another List, with 1500 Lines, mixed up between other lines, where I have lots of additional information, that I need to have added to list one.

- xWDL15-B01;DATA2;DATA3;TEST;OK;GREAT
- xWDL15-CD01;DATA2;DATA3;TEST;OK;GREAT
- xWDL15BM-V02;DATA2;DATA3;TEST;OK;GREAT
- xWDL15-V01;DATA2;DATA3;TEST;OK;GREAT
- xROHVS10-V09;DATA2;DATA3;TEST;OK;GREAT
- xDAEMBEK13-V09;DATA2;DATA3;TEST;OK;GREAT
- xFEBG16_V10;DATA2;DATA3;TEST;OK;GREAT

So how can I find/match/extract all those lines at once?

Is there an easier way, then to go over it 200 times and copy/paste, search, copy/paste? Probably there is.

Do you know one?

A Solution in Sublime Text or Excel or something would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctrl + shift + f` or `Mac + shift + f` to open up search bar. Type the query you want to match and press `Find All`.

You can then use `replace` to replace them all.

If you want to search over multiple files you can use Browse option to select the paths.

Comment: thanks for your quick awnser. however I need to mark them, not replace them, so I can extract the needed lines.

Comment: Yeah, if you use find all it will highlight them all

Comment: How can I match multiple lines/words at once or find them in all lines and mark them?

Comment: This is the point of the question, to match multiple lines (200) at once and get the full content of the lines by using Shift+END or something to match the whole line, however I can't get 200 cursors on these lines at once, any idea?

Comment: No, as far to my knowledge that is not possible with sublime. Though you can select multiple lines cursors by holding press.